# ZK with Spring Session jdbc throws: Unable to serialize entry

Tags: spring, session, zk

We have an aplication based on ZK with Spring Boot / Spring Security / JPA implementation running in Google Cloud Run, within a docker. It works quite fine with non jdbc persistent sessions. Google is probably sending the requests with the same JSESSION_ID to same server of the server pool.
Unfortunatelly, too often the aplication closes and the user has to relogin, probably when the server previously answering the requests is shutdown or becomes too busy and Google decides to change the destination server.

Our idea to improve usability was to implement the Spring persistent session which is very easy to implement. It is just about adding in the Pom :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and the .properties :

```
 spring.session.store-type=jdbc
 spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
```

The table for holding the session data is created, the server starts, but when trying to load the login page we get the following error :

```
    2022-01-04 16:50:19.395  INFO 15092 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] o.z.util.resource.impl.LabelLoaderImpl   : Loading labels for es
    2022-01-04 16:50:19.396  INFO 15092 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] o.z.util.resource.impl.LabelLoaderImpl   : Opening file:/C:/gitlab/hov2-springboot/target/classes/metainfo/zk-label_es.properties
    2022-01-04 16:50:19.399  INFO 15092 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] o.z.util.resource.impl.LabelLoaderImpl   : Opening file:/C:/gitlab/hov2-springboot/target/classes/metainfo/zk-label.properties
    2022-01-04 16:50:19.615 ERROR 15092 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] org.zkoss.io.serializable                : Unable to serialize entry: $composer=org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer@45f1b067
    2022-01-04 16:50:19.718 ERROR 15092 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/V2].[auEngine]           : Servlet.service() for servlet [auEngine] threw exception
    
    org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object] to type [byte[]] for value 'org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession@1f9bd946'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException
```

This error looks like this is one of the ZK framework object that is not serializable, I double checked that all the session data is serializable and did not find any thing wrong on that side.

I can add here some config files in this post, but i basically followed the instruccions from :

https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Setting_up_Servers/Google_App_Engine

Any help to succeed implementing the Spring Session store with ZK is welcome !

This is a "org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" Object that fails to serialize any idea why ?

as per very good Hawk idea, here is the log with the detailed error log :

```
    2022-01-05 12:45:20.410 ERROR 27596 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] org.zkoss.io.serializable                : Unable to serialize entry: $composer=org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer@38cc879f
    2022-01-05 12:45:20.508 ERROR 27596 --- [nio-8443-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/V2].[auEngine]           : Servlet.service() for servlet [auEngine] threw exception
    
    org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object] to type [byte[]] for value 'org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession@7f4fb979'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor
        - field (class "org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractGenericPointcutAdvisor", name: "advice", type: "interface org.aopalliance.aop.Advice")
        - object (class "org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor", org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor@586a49e8])
        - custom writeObject data (class "java.util.ArrayList")
        - object (class "java.util.ArrayList", [org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.ADVISOR, org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor@586a49e8], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor@5f18770], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor@6aa74b32], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor@64eec21d], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor@6ec1e261], org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor@18709cb2])
        - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport", name: "advisors", type: "interface java.util.List")
        - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory", org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 3 interfaces [com.vyv.hov2.repository.ConfRepository, org.springframework.data.repository.Repository, org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionalProxy]; 7 advisors [org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.ADVISOR, org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor@586a49e8], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor@5f18770], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor@6aa74b32], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor@64eec21d], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor@6ec1e261], org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor@18709cb2]; targetSource [SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.vyv.hov2.repository.CustomRepositoryImpl@776682b]]; proxyTargetClass=false; optimize=false; opaque=false; exposeProxy=false; frozen=false)
        - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy", name: "advised", type: "class org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport")
        - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy", org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy@88477f8a)
        - field (class "java.lang.reflect.Proxy", name: "h", type: "interface java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler")
        - object (class "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy170", com.vyv.hov2.repository.CustomRepositoryImpl@776682b)
        - field (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl", name: "confRepository", type: "interface com.vyv.hov2.repository.ConfRepository")
        - object (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl", com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f)
        - field (class "org.springframework.aop.target.SingletonTargetSource", name: "target", type: "class java.lang.Object")
        - object (class "org.springframework.aop.target.SingletonTargetSource", SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f])
        - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport", name: "targetSource", type: "interface org.springframework.aop.TargetSource")
        - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory", org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 0 interfaces []; 1 advisors [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor: advice org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor@4f64d9cb]; targetSource [SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f]]; proxyTargetClass=true; optimize=false; opaque=false; exposeProxy=false; frozen=false)
        - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor", name: "advised", type: "class org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport")
        - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor", org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor@2b88fa68)
        - field (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1da6c3fa", name: "CGLIB$CALLBACK_0", type: "interface org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor")
        - object (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1da6c3fa", com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f)
        - field (class "com.vyv.hov2.viewModel.LoginViewModel", name: "confB", type: "interface com.vyv.hov2.business.ConfBusiness")
        - object (class "com.vyv.hov2.viewModel.LoginViewModel", com.vyv.hov2.viewModel.LoginViewModel@15d2453)
        - field (class "org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer", name: "_viewModel", type: "class java.lang.Object")
        - object (class "org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer", org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer@38cc879f)
        - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent")
        - object (class "org.zkoss.zul.Window", <Window yH5Q0#win>)
        - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractPage")
        - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl", [Page yH5Q_])
        - custom writeObject data (class "java.util.LinkedList")
        - object (class "java.util.LinkedList", [[Page yH5Q_]])
        - field (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl", name: "_pages", type: "interface java.util.List")
        - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl")
        - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl", [Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul])
        - field (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap$Value", name: "value", type: "class java.lang.Object")
        - object (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap$Value", ([Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul]@1641404719684))
        - custom writeObject data (class "java.util.HashMap")
        - object (class "java.util.LinkedHashMap", {z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ=([Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul]@1641404719684)})
        - field (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap", name: "_map", type: "interface java.util.Map")
        - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap")
        - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache$Cache", {z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ=[Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul]})
        - field (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache", name: "_desktops", type: "class org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache$Cache")
        - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache", org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache@8570f71)
        - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession")
        - root object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession", org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession@7f4fb979)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractGenericPointcutAdvisor", name: "advice", type: "interface org.aopalliance.aop.Advice")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor", org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor@586a49e8])
    - custom writeObject data (class "java.util.ArrayList")
    - object (class "java.util.ArrayList", [org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.ADVISOR, org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor@586a49e8], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor@5f18770], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor@6aa74b32], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor@64eec21d], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor@6ec1e261], org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor@18709cb2])
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport", name: "advisors", type: "interface java.util.List")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory", org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 3 interfaces [com.vyv.hov2.repository.ConfRepository, org.springframework.data.repository.Repository, org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionalProxy]; 7 advisors [org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.ADVISOR, org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor@586a49e8], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor@5f18770], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor@6aa74b32], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor@64eec21d], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor@6ec1e261], org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor@18709cb2]; targetSource [SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.vyv.hov2.repository.CustomRepositoryImpl@776682b]]; proxyTargetClass=false; optimize=false; opaque=false; exposeProxy=false; frozen=false)
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy", name: "advised", type: "class org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy", org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy@88477f8a)
    - field (class "java.lang.reflect.Proxy", name: "h", type: "interface java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler")
    - object (class "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy170", com.vyv.hov2.repository.CustomRepositoryImpl@776682b)
    - field (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl", name: "confRepository", type: "interface com.vyv.hov2.repository.ConfRepository")
    - object (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl", com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f)
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.target.SingletonTargetSource", name: "target", type: "class java.lang.Object")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.target.SingletonTargetSource", SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f])
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport", name: "targetSource", type: "interface org.springframework.aop.TargetSource")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory", org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 0 interfaces []; 1 advisors [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor: advice org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor@4f64d9cb]; targetSource [SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f]]; proxyTargetClass=true; optimize=false; opaque=false; exposeProxy=false; frozen=false)
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor", name: "advised", type: "class org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor", org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor@2b88fa68)
    - field (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1da6c3fa", name: "CGLIB$CALLBACK_0", type: "interface org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor")
    - object (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1da6c3fa", com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f)
    - field (class "com.vyv.hov2.viewModel.LoginViewModel", name: "confB", type: "interface com.vyv.hov2.business.ConfBusiness")
    - object (class "com.vyv.hov2.viewModel.LoginViewModel", com.vyv.hov2.viewModel.LoginViewModel@15d2453)
    - field (class "org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer", name: "_viewModel", type: "class java.lang.Object")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer", org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer@38cc879f)
    - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.zul.Window", <Window yH5Q0#win>)
    - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractPage")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl", [Page yH5Q_])
    - custom writeObject data (class "java.util.LinkedList")
    - object (class "java.util.LinkedList", [[Page yH5Q_]])
    - field (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl", name: "_pages", type: "interface java.util.List")
    - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl", [Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul])
    - field (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap$Value", name: "value", type: "class java.lang.Object")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap$Value", ([Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul]@1641404719684))
    - custom writeObject data (class "java.util.HashMap")
    - object (class "java.util.LinkedHashMap", {z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ=([Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul]@1641404719684)})
    - field (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap", name: "_map", type: "interface java.util.Map")
    - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache$Cache", {z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ=[Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul]})
    - field (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache", name: "_desktops", type: "class org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache$Cache")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache", org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache@8570f71)
    - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession")
    - root object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession", org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession@7f4fb979)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:33)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:386)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    ... 155 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractGenericPointcutAdvisor", name: "advice", type: "interface org.aopalliance.aop.Advice")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor", org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor@586a49e8])
    - custom writeObject data (class "java.util.ArrayList")
    - object (class "java.util.ArrayList", [org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.ADVISOR, org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor@586a49e8], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor@5f18770], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor@6aa74b32], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor@64eec21d], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor@6ec1e261], org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor@18709cb2])
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport", name: "advisors", type: "interface java.util.List")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory", org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 3 interfaces [com.vyv.hov2.repository.ConfRepository, org.springframework.data.repository.Repository, org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionalProxy]; 7 advisors [org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.ADVISOR, org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor@586a49e8], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor@5f18770], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor@6aa74b32], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor@64eec21d], org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor: pointcut [Pointcut.TRUE]; advice [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor@6ec1e261], org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor@18709cb2]; targetSource [SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.vyv.hov2.repository.CustomRepositoryImpl@776682b]]; proxyTargetClass=false; optimize=false; opaque=false; exposeProxy=false; frozen=false)
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy", name: "advised", type: "class org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy", org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy@88477f8a)
    - field (class "java.lang.reflect.Proxy", name: "h", type: "interface java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler")
    - object (class "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy170", com.vyv.hov2.repository.CustomRepositoryImpl@776682b)
    - field (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl", name: "confRepository", type: "interface com.vyv.hov2.repository.ConfRepository")
    - object (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl", com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f)
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.target.SingletonTargetSource", name: "target", type: "class java.lang.Object")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.target.SingletonTargetSource", SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f])
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport", name: "targetSource", type: "interface org.springframework.aop.TargetSource")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory", org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 0 interfaces []; 1 advisors [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor: advice org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor@4f64d9cb]; targetSource [SingletonTargetSource for target object [com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f]]; proxyTargetClass=true; optimize=false; opaque=false; exposeProxy=false; frozen=false)
    - field (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor", name: "advised", type: "class org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport")
    - object (class "org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor", org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor@2b88fa68)
    - field (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1da6c3fa", name: "CGLIB$CALLBACK_0", type: "interface org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor")
    - object (class "com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1da6c3fa", com.vyv.hov2.business.impl.ConfBusinessImpl@6f377b1f)
    - field (class "com.vyv.hov2.viewModel.LoginViewModel", name: "confB", type: "interface com.vyv.hov2.business.ConfBusiness")
    - object (class "com.vyv.hov2.viewModel.LoginViewModel", com.vyv.hov2.viewModel.LoginViewModel@15d2453)
    - field (class "org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer", name: "_viewModel", type: "class java.lang.Object")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer", org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer@38cc879f)
    - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.zul.Window", <Window yH5Q0#win>)
    - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractPage")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.PageImpl", [Page yH5Q_])
    - custom writeObject data (class "java.util.LinkedList")
    - object (class "java.util.LinkedList", [[Page yH5Q_]])
    - field (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl", name: "_pages", type: "interface java.util.List")
    - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.DesktopImpl", [Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul])
    - field (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap$Value", name: "value", type: "class java.lang.Object")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap$Value", ([Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul]@1641404719684))
    - custom writeObject data (class "java.util.HashMap")
    - object (class "java.util.LinkedHashMap", {z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ=([Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul]@1641404719684)})
    - field (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap", name: "_map", type: "interface java.util.Map")
    - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.util.CacheMap")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache$Cache", {z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ=[Desktop z_Jbfu8exW9haA_LuuwzUJCQ:/zul/login.zul]})
    - field (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache", name: "_desktops", type: "class org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache$Cache")
    - object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache", org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.SimpleDesktopCache@8570f71)
    - custom writeObject data (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession")
    - root object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession", org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession@7f4fb979)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please call `System.setProperty("sun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo", "true");` which will print details debugging information about which member field is not serializable.

---

updated:

If you check the exception, the last field it printed is the root cause of `NotSerializableException`:

```
- field (class "org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractGenericPointcutAdvisor", name: "advice", type: "interface org.aopalliance.aop.Advice")
```

You can trace the object path from the root object to know how your ViewModel references `AbstractGenericPointcutAdvisor`.

```
- root object (class "org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession", org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableSession@7f4fb979)
```

Hence, I think the exception is not caused by ZK.

Comment: thanks Hawk for your quick response ! I updated the question with the detailed log but i can't find any more clue into it, the log now shows all what Spring tries to serialize but i cannot identify if it gives information about a specific data that would fail to serialize, I can see : - object (class "org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer", org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer@38cc879f) within this list of objects but not more info why it would fail... Any other idea to go one step further ?